# How do i refresh my datagridview after inserting new SQL data using vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, visual-studio

To elaborate my project i have 4 forms the 1st one is the main, i used panel
to switch from the other 3 forms, although the inserting of data is working
i want to see the updated sql column in the table after i inserted from the other form but when i tried to refresh the datagrid it doesn't work i have to close the program and start again just to load the new data in the datagridview.

I've tried:

```
DataGridView1.Refresh();
```

and `load_table()` but it doesn't work for me.

**This is the code that display the tables on my database(2nd form):**

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class search

    Dim cn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand




    Public Sub DataGridView1_ParentChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ParentChanged
        cn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=4102123; database=pis"
        Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
        Dim bSource As New BindingSource
        Try
            cn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "select * from pis.patient_info"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, cn)
            SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
            SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
            bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
            SDA.Update(dbDataSet)

            cn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End Sub


End Class
```

**This is the main code(1st form):**

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim cn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand

    Private Sub OvalShape1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        switchpanel(search)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        switchpanel(add)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        switchpanel(del)
    End Sub

    Sub switchpanel(ByVal panel As Form)
        Panel1.Controls.Clear()
        panel.TopLevel = False
        Panel1.Controls.Add(panel)
        panel.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Code i use for insertion of data(3rd form):**

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class add
    Dim cn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        cn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=4102123; database=pis;"
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            cn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "insert into pis.patient_info(Name) values('" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, cn)
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

            cn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub


End Class
```

**Is it possible to call another form or class on different forms?**
For example: from the main form above i'll call the 2nd form to execute the code
again, because once i click the button from the main the program code only
execute once, when i switch forms to 3rd and 1st form then come back to 2nd form
the datagridview will not refresh anymore, instead the code that will work only
is the `switchpanel(search)` and displays not updated datagridview.

Comment: Can you show us how `you are currently loading the data`? If you loading routine is wrapped up in a method you can call, why don't you just call that method?

Comment: Quickest solution - just call `DataGridView1_ParentChanged(Nothing, Nothing)`

Comment: from the main form i switch panel to the other form and the datagrid is located in there, that's why i can't use other solutions like load_table()

Comment: ok i'll try that @Fabio

Comment: it doesn't work @Fabio it causes an error StackOverFlow Exception

Comment: Based on update you need to call `Button1_Click(Nothing, Nothing)`

Comment: Please don't post images of code. How can we copy, paste and execute code that is in an image? Code is text. Post it as text and then format it as code.

Comment: ok @jmcilhinney

Comment: @Fabio it doesn't work either once i call Button1_Click(Nothing, Nothing) it creates multiple data into my database repeatedly