# How can i show the first panel that shows when i load my first form using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

This is the code for main:

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class main
    Dim cn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FilterData("")
    End Sub
    Private Sub main(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FilterData("")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Resize()
        Static IsAlreadyResized As Boolean
        If Not IsAlreadyResized Then
            Me.WindowState = vbMaximizedFocus
            IsAlreadyResized = True
        End If
    End Sub



    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        add.Dispose()
        switchpanel(search)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        search.Dispose()
        switchpanel(add)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        switchpanel(del)
    End Sub

    Sub switchpanel(ByVal panel As Form)
        Panel1.Controls.Clear()
        panel.TopLevel = False
        Panel1.Controls.Add(panel)
        panel.Show()
    End Sub

    Public Sub FilterData(valueToSearch As String)
        cn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=4102123; database=pis"
        Dim SearchQuery As String = "select * from pis.patient_info where concat(patient_id,Name,Birth_Date,Birth_Place,Address,Nationality,Religion,Civil_Status,Age,Occupation,Gender,Blood_Type,Medical_History) like '%" & valueToSearch & "%'"
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand(SearchQuery, cn)
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        DataGridView1.Hide()

        adapter.Fill(table)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = table

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click
        search.Close()
        add.Close()
        Application.Restart()
        Me.Height = 900
        FilterData(TextBox1.Text)
        DataGridView1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseLeave
        FilterData(TextBox1.Text)
        DataGridView1.Hide()
    End Sub

    Public Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

        FilterData(TextBox1.Text)
        DataGridView1.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

This is the code where it must go back from the main code, or just display the
datagridview1 when i'm typing in the textbox, it works when i uses the code `Application.Restart()` and before switching to other panels, but when i switch panels in different form and want to search again it does not display, i want to display the datagridview1 just like when i started the program without restarting it `Application.Restart()`

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click
        search.Close()
        add.Close()
        Application.Restart()
        Me.Height = 900
        FilterData(TextBox1.Text)
        DataGridView1.Show()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create another sub that contains
`DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing;
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); DataGridView1.Refresh();`

And then call that sub instead of the application restart. Just make sure that each time after this sub is called you setup the DataSource for the datagridview again. Skimming through your code I believe your FilterData method already has that covered but I figured I'd mention it.

Comment: `Private Sub Reload()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click
        search.Hide()
        add.Hide()
        del.Hide()
        Call Reload()
        FilterData(TextBox1.Text)
        DataGridView1.Show()
    End Sub`

Comment: i think your answer is right but i think what's blocking to display the data again is the panel that i'm using when i clicked the button to switch panels, it stuck on that same panel, is there any solution to go back in the same panel i'm using when my program start?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure what the problem you are having is. Without seeing the rest of your code there isn't much else I can suggest. I know your FilterData sub hides your datagridview everytime it is called which I think would not be what you want to happen

Comment: i used this code to fix my problem 'Dim newform As main
        newform = New main()
        newform.Show()
        Me.Dispose()'

Comment: i duplicated my form to refresh the program and redisplay the panel, i think it's the only way because i can't switch panel from the same form. the rest of the code is posted in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912956/how-do-i-refresh-my-datagridview-after-inserting-new-sql-data-using-vb-net?noredirect=1#comment96596471_54912956